# How to use "doc" tag in Nokogiri to build an XML document

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a problem: I must build an XML document with a `<doc>` tag. I can use any custom tag except "doc".

I need to use "doc".  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an underscore to the name to prevent it being seen as an existing method. See the section “Special Tags” in the [Nokogiri Builder docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder).

Something like:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  # Note the underscore here:
  xml.doc_ "A doc tag"
end
```

This example produces the following XML (the underscore isn’t included in the tag name):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>A doc tag</doc>
```

Comment: ...which now begs the question - how does one build an element whose name has a trailing underscore? =P

Comment: @maerics Two trailing underscores will build an element with one trailing underscore.